# Phonegap - android - image saved in cache if orientation set to true

Tags: android, image, cordova, caching, orientation

On setting correctOrientation : true, then image rotation issue is solved and thumbnail is set - But image path is: file://storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.examole.helloworld/modified.jpg?149028394994

Without correctOrientation: true, image path is: file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/1490345556009.jpg

When trying to set another image with correctOrientation: true, then the latest selected image is not set.
Following is the code for your kind reference:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(captureSuccess, onFail, {quality: 50,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM,
        mediaType: Camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
        correctOrientation: true,
        allowEdit: true
 });
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: For those finding this much later, this issue has now been resolved in the latest version of cordova-plugin-camera. Upgrade the plugin to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this and posted my answer

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(captureSuccess, onFail, {quality: 50,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM,
        mediaType: Camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
        correctOrientation: true,
});

var captureSuccess = function(mediaFiles) {
     var fD = mediaFiles;
     window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(fD, function(fileEntry) {
       fileEntry.file(function(fT) {
         var fname = fileEntry.nativeURL.substr(fileEntry.nativeURL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
         fileTransferUpload(fD,fname);
       }, function() {
       console.log('error');
       });
    }, onFError);
};
```

the method fileTransferUpload above will just set the image path in src.

in success callback function, image path is received and without getting nativeURL from this path, i have set the path itself in src.

Answer (score 1):

```
You can try this,      

  $(document).on('click','.capture_photo',function(){
                navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, {
                  quality : 75,
                  destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
                  sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
                  encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.PNG,
                  popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
                  saveToPhotoAlbum: false 
                });
            }); 
        // to call the success function of capture image(onPhotoDataSuccess)
             function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) { 
              sessionStorage.setItem("img_api",imageData);
              $('#captureimg').attr('src','data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData);
                App.show_toast("Profile image updated successfully!");
            }
       //onfail
    onFail(message) { alert('Failed because: ' + message); }
```

Comment: Thanks San. But this is not working. and i need to pick from gallery, so i am using sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM

Answer (score 1):

Here's a better solution (involved a spot of digging through some Java files, but takes about 8 seconds)

in CameraLauncher.java (in the cordova-plugin-camera/src/android folder)

```
//Old:
String modifiedPath = getTempDirectoryPath() + "/modified"+".jpg";
this.callbackContext.success("file://" + modifiedPath + "?" + System.currentTimeMillis());
```

AKA just move the timestamp up in the filename.

```
//New:    
String modifiedPath = getTempDirectoryPath() + "/modified"+  System.currentTimeMillis() +".jpg";
this.callbackContext.success("file://" + modifiedPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
    var pictureSource;   // picture source
    var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value
    function onDeviceReady() {
        pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
        destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
    }
```

sorry, you want to add this code along with the that.